# Visualising a linear model using effects package in R

Tags: r, regression, data-visualization, modeling

I have ran this model in R:

```
model <- lm(mpg ~ hp + drat + disp, data=mtcars)
```

And I have visualised this model using `effects` package in `R`:

```
library(effects)
model_effects <- effect("hp", model, list(drat=mean(mtcars$drat), disp = mean(mtcars$disp)))
plot(model_effects)
```

[image]

I believe this plot shows the relationship between `mpg` and `hp` whilst holding `drat` and `disp` constant at their mean values. Could somebody confirm this is what the plot is doing?

Comment: (Is this on topic for CV?) Yes, and in fact you will get the same result if you merely type `effect("hp", model)`.  See the `typical` argument in the documentation for `effect`.  You can also double-check that the function is working as intended by plotting prediction lines using `predict`.